# Using tibbles in r, set default to print 3 digits to the right of the decimal place

Tags: r, tibble

I'm just starting to use tibbles and I'm dealing with financial futures data which may have 3 places to the right of the decimal point.  When I print a tibble, it shows only 2 digits to the right of the decimal point and sometimes I would like to see 3.  I tried,

```
library (tidyverse)
options.sigfig=3

price <- tibble(a=24.50,b=1.875)
price

> price
# A tibble: 1 x 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  24.5  1.88
```

I know I can move the tibble data to a data frame to get what I want.

```
dfPrice <- as.data.frame(price)
dfPrice
> dfPrice
 a     b
1 24.5 1.875
```

Is there any way I can eliminate this extra step and get the tibble to print the way a data frame prints?

Comment: maybe `pillar.sigfig`?

Comment: the way to set options is `options(pillar.sigfig = 3)`, but this still does not seem to be what you want, ie, showing 3 digits past the decimal. `sigfig` appears to be the elementary school definition of "significant figures" which idk why would be useful to anyone

Comment: this might help: https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/formatting.html

Comment: @rawr is correct. sigfig counts digits from the left, regardless of where the decimal point is located. Using 10.123 in a tibble with sigfig set to 4, prints 10.12. So that's NOT a solution that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

@EJJ had the right idea.  Use:

```
options(pillar.sigfig=4)
```